# Alignment problems for panels

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi please take a look at this link. How can I make the image to be in the centre as of right now it seems to be going to the right too much

http://jsbin.com/yenade

Answer (score 0):

demo - http://jsbin.com/xacikizuhe/

use `left: 50%;` and `transform: translateX(-50%);`

```
.panel-profile .panel-heading img {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  bottom: -25px;
}
```

```css
/*demo */

body {
  padding: 5%;
}
.panel {
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto
}
/* end demo */

.panel-profile .panel-heading {
  position: relative;
}
.panel-profile .panel-heading h4 {
  margin: 10px 0 20px;
  font-weight: normal;
}
.panel-profile .panel-heading img {
  margin: 0 auto 10px;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  background: #fff;
}
@media (min-width: 400px) {
  .panel-profile .panel-heading a {
    font-size: .75em;
    float: right;
  }
  .panel-profile .panel-heading {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
  }
  .panel-profile .panel-heading img {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    bottom: -25px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel panel-default panel-profile">
  <div class="panel-heading text-center clearfix">
    <h4>Name of Person</h4>
    <img src="http://placepic.me/profiles/50-50" class="img-circle">

    <a href="#">Edit Profile</a> 
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    Panel content
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you wanted to horizontally center the image right? @failedStudent

Comment: Opps! Thanks! I wanted to make the image in the centre of the "name of person" so it should be around "of"? @Vitorino Fernandes

Comment: Hi @Vitorino Fernandes I wanted something like this 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/l0gd3teu18t2sec/Screenshot%202014-11-15%2021.51.27.png?dl=0

As you can see the that circle image is aligned in the middle with the name.